# Creating a Dummy Controller for Rails Concerns not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm trying to dynamically create a controller to test my rails controller concern with, based on [this example](http://ridingtheclutch.com/post/55701769414/testing-controller-concerns-in-rails).

My code looks like this

```
require 'test_helper'

class RequireAuthenticationTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "Throws token required error" do
    @controller = RequireAuthenticationTestController.new(:index) { require_authentication; render :nothing => true }
    get :index

    assert_response :success
  end
end

class RequireAuthenticationTestController < ActionController::Base
  include RequireAuthentication

  def initialize(method_name, &method_body)
    self.class.send(:define_method, method_name, method_body)
  end
end
```

Whenever I try to run the code however, I get the error

> RequireAuthenticationTest#test_Throws_token_required_error:
>   ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches
>   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"require_authentication_test"}
>       test/controllers/concerns/require_authentication_test.rb:7:in `block in '

Any advice on what I am doing wrong with this? Thanks!

Comment: can you post your RequireAuthentication code as well?

Comment: I don't think it is relevant. The problem is that the controller route isn't being recognized. My RequireAuthentication code isn't even being called.

Comment: Hum. I'm getting an error trying to run the code from the blog post. Which version of Rails and mini test are you using?

Comment: Rails 4.1.6 and Minitest 5.4.2

Comment: Did you figure it out eventually? If so, would you be so kind to answer your own question. I'm looking at the exact some problem right now.

Comment: Sorry, I never did figure this out. I just testing using an existing controller

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to define a route for your test controller. This is code I am using to test my breadcrumbs:

```
require 'test_helper'
class BreadcrumbTest < ActionController::TestCase

  test "Throws token required error" do
    @controller = BreadcrumbTestsController.new( :index ) { render :nothing => true }

    with_routing do |set|
      set.draw do
        resources :breadcrumb_tests
      end

      begin
        get :index
        assert_response :success
      end

    end
  end
end

class BreadcrumbTestsController < ActionController::Base
  include BreadcrumbList

  def initialize(method_name, &method_body)
    self.class.send(:define_method, method_name, method_body)
  end

end
```

... but I cannot explain why this works.